# How to set dynamic print area for dynamic worksheets in EpPlus?

Tags: c#, epplus

My application generates excel sheet with different dynamic worksheet names. I want to set this formula `"=OFFSET(worksheet_name!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(worksheet_name!$A$1:$A$10),5)"`
for all those worksheets with dynamic worksheet name in **Print_Area**. How Can I achieve this in EP Plus?

Comment: When you say Dynamic, are YOU generating the WS names?  If so, why not simply insert them yourself in code with `var formula  = "=OFFSET({WsNameStringVariable}!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(worksheet_name!$A$1:$A$10),5)"`?  If you are doing something different post the code.

Comment: My bad, I meant I want to set this formula for different worksheet for **Pint_Area**.